# Bootstrap Plugins Using Theme

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have this Plugin I want to use, it is a slider plugin, here's the link to it: https://github.com/seiyria/bootstrap-slider

I want use it using the CDN: https://cdnjs.com/libraries/bootstrap-slider

So in my header of the html I have it like this:

```
    <head>
        <title>Slider Test</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-slider/9.2.0/bootstrap-slider.js"></script>
        <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-slider/9.2.0/bootstrap-slider.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-slider/9.2.0/css/bootstrap-slider.css"></script>
        <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-slider/9.2.0/css/bootstrap-slider.min.css"></script>
    </head>
```

And then I try to use one of the examples they show on their page: http://seiyria.com/bootstrap-slider/

Example 21:

```
<input id="ex21" type="text"
          data-provide="slider"
          data-slider-ticks="[1, 2, 3]"
          data-slider-ticks-labels='["short", "medium", "long"]'
          data-slider-min="1"
          data-slider-max="3"
          data-slider-step="1"
          data-slider-value="3"
          data-slider-tooltip="hide" />
```

As a result all I get is a text box. Am I not using the plugin or referencing it the right way ?

Answer (score 1):

First: you only need either the full or the minfied versions. In your example code you're including both.

For development purposes I propose to remove the includes of the minified files (the one with the `.min` suffix.

Secondly, you are including the stylesheets through `script` tags. You need to include a stylesheet using a `link` tag.

Lastly, I do not see an include of the Bootstrap JavaScript itself, you'll need to include it as well.

I would also update the path to the bootstrap-slider files. Using two slashes at the start could lead to strange behaviour. Update them to use `https://` as the prefix.

After these changes your `head` section should look like

```
<head>
    <title>Slider Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-slider/9.2.0/css/bootstrap-slider.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-slider/9.2.0/bootstrap-slider.js"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: Did exactly this, but I am still getting an empty text box

Comment: Open Developer Tools (on Chrome it's F12) and see if you get any errors logged in the console

Comment: Yes I do, I get the following:

`file://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-slider/9.2.0/css/bootstrap-slider.css Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
file://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-slider/9.2.0/bootstrap-slider.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`

Comment: When I add the `https:` to the links, the errors go away but I still have an empty text box.

Comment: And you have included Bootstrap itself?